# Enabling the correct network interface on boot

Tags: ubuntu, networking, drivers, usb, networkmanager

I have a laptop with an integrated WiFi interface `wlo1`. I recently installed a USB  network adapter and installed the correct driver. I ran the following commands to check that the adapter works using the following commands:

```
sudo ip link set wlo1 down
sudo ip link set wlx001f017ae8b8 up
```

This worked flawlessly. To ensure that my machine uses the correct interface on boot, I added this file to `/etc/init.d` and made a service in `/etc/systemd/system/custom_net.service`:

```
[Unit] 
Description=The custom net manager for the driver and hardware WiFi chips. 

[Service] 
ExecStart=/bin/bash /etc/init.d/Custom_NetStart.sh 

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I ran `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and enabled the service. But, every time I reboot, it doesn't work. It just uses my built-in network interface. I ensured that the service works by running `sudo systemctl restart custom_net.service`. This worked and enabled my USB network adapter.

I ensured that the executable had executing permissions and even tried adding it to Cron with `@reboot /etc/init.d/Custom_NetStart.sh`. This also doesn't work. What can I do?

I would prefer to not blacklist my built-in network interface in modprobe incase I want to switch to it in the future.

---

System Info:

- OS: Zorin Pro 16.2 (Ubuntu 20.04)

Output from `iwconfig` **on boot**:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"IronLan"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.805 GHz  Access Point: 08:36:C9:EE:BD:FE   
          Bit Rate=292.6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=41/70  Signal level=-69 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:92   Missed beacon:0

wlx001f017ae8b8  IEEE 802.11AC  ESSID:"IronLan"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.805 GHz  Access Point: 08:36:C9:EE:BD:FE   
          Bit Rate:867 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=85/100  Signal level=-64 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Output from `sudo ip route list` **on boot**:

```
default via 192.168.30.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
default via 192.168.30.1 dev wlx001f017ae8b8 proto dhcp metric 601 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.30.0/23 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.30.18 metric 600 
192.168.30.0/23 dev wlx001f017ae8b8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.31.240 metric 601
```

---

Any help is truly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more information about the problem.

**If this question doesn't belong on this exchange, please let me know where to post it.**

Comment: You should better manage this directly in the network manager of your choice (NetworkManager or ifupdown) ....